# Migrating Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 from Windows 2003 x86 / MSEE to Windows 2008 R2 x64 / SQL Server 2008

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration, sql-server

I am having a helluva time with this one.

I am attempting to migrate a 5 year old VM running Windows 2003 Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 that was deployed as a standalone (thus to MSEE) to a Windows 2008 R2 x64 WSS3 implementation with SQL Server Standard 2008R2.

I was successful in getting the 14GB content DB moved over so now the standalone Win2k3 farm has its content DB on the 2008 machine (yay!).

However trying to get the config db & admincontent DB over has been troublesome. I have looked and followed the technet articles but seem to have no luck in resolving issues.

Is it best just to roll out a new farm and hook the new configuration into the old content DB or do I continue to try to preserve the configuration in the config DB & admin content DB (there aren't many customizations in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

I'd just build a new farm on the new machine, add solutions and then add the content database.

You might need [SPSolutionExtractor](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPSolutionExtractor)

Answer (score -1):

I would strongly recomand you build your own MOSS 2007 server farm and go through a series of database attach/upgrade (i mean SharePoint 2007 attach to an existing farm, and it will force an upgrade).

Before that, make sure you identified all customizations, 3rd party developments, etc.

Comment: Missed the WSS 3.0 - updated.